# Unity (Mac) Cannot input sprite name on sprite editor dialog

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity Personal (Free version)

I am trying to rename sprite name from 'greenSheet_2' to something else, but i can't type any single letter after 'Name' of sprite editor dialog (Cannot copy and paste also).

I have no idea why?
Is this bug or limitation for free version or something? 
[image]

Comment: Check the read/write enabled box in import settings.